# On cohomological algebras related to toric manifolds

Tags: homological-algebra, cohomology, toric-varieties

I am interested in some cohomological algebras related to toric manifolds. We consider a toric manifold $M$ as a quotient
$$M = P^{-1}(p) / \mathbb{K}, \quad P : \mathbb{C}^n \to \text{Lie}(\mathbb{K})^*,$$ where $P$ is the momentum map associated with the linear action of a torus $\mathbb{K} \subset (S^1)^n$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$, and $p$ is a regular value of $P$.

The cohomology of $M$ can be expressed in terms of two ideals in the algebra $\mathbb{C}[u_1,...,u_n]$ of polynomial functions on $\mathbb{C}^n := \text{Lie}((S^1)^n) \otimes \mathbb{C}$, the exponents $m = (m_1,...,m_n)$ of which we view as elements of $\ker(\exp : \text{Lie}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \to (S^1)^n)$:

1. $I$ the ideal of polynomials vanishing on $\mathbb{C}^k := \text{Lie}(\mathbb{K}) \otimes \mathbb{C} \subset \mathbb{C}^n$;
2. $J$ the ideal generated by monomials $u^m := u_1^{m_1}...u_n^{m_n}$ such that $m$, considered as a function on $\mathbb{R}^{n*} = \text{Lie}((S^1)^n)^*$, assumes strictly positive values on the polyhedron $(i^*)^{-1}(p) \cap \mathbb{R}^{n*}_{>0}$, where $i^* : \mathbb{R}^{n*} \to \text{Lie}(\mathbb{K})^*$ is the map induced by the inclusion $\mathbb{K} \overset{i}{\hookrightarrow} (S^1)^n$.

We have: $$H^*(M,\mathbb{C}) \simeq \mathbb{C}[u_1,...,u_n]\  / \ (I+J).$$

---

Let me modify $J$ a little bit, and define the following submodule $J_r$ of $\mathbb{C}[u_1,...,u_n]$:
$$J_r \text{ is generated by monomials } u^m \text{ for which } \  m \in \ker(\exp : \text{Lie}(\mathbb{K}) \to \mathbb{K}) \ \text{ and } \ p(m) \geq r.$$

Notice that for $r > 0$, we have $J_r \subset J$.

---

It is well-known that the cohomology of any smooth projective variety (in particular $M$) is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. However, I have trouble understanding why the same property should be true for the cohomological algebra

$$\mathbb{C}[u_1,...,u_n] \ / \ (I + J_r).$$

I would be grateful if someone had an idea.